# Mysql query with auto kill embedded

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to create an MySQL query that kills itself if it takes too long to complete? I would like to know if is possible to predict average time spent on querying, and prevent database exhausting. Is there some tool or native trick tha allow us to do this?

For instance:

```
SELECT data FROM unpredictable KILL IF TIMEOUT > 2000 /* ms */
```

**Enviroment:** 5.6.19 MySQL

Answer (score 1):

1. For MySQL 5.7.4 you can for top level read-only SELECT statements

[server-side-select-statement-timeouts](http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/)

For example:

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000;
```

---

2. You could also try change timeout setting in your server

Edit my.cnf (the MySQL configuration file).

```
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

[how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server)

Comment: Is there any similar feature available for MySQL 5.6.12? For now, I am unable to upgrade the environment )-:

Comment: +1, The my.cnf exist in all Mysql server versions...do a `find -name "my.cnf` from your root directory to locate yours..